# Slider works but with a delay

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the problem with my slider. When I load my website it works well, but when I go to another tab in my browser and return the slider works but with a **delay**.

This is how it looks at the beginning:[Before](http://uploadfile.pl/pokaz/1316253---jdwo.html)

That's how it looks after some time, just change the tab in the browser and this delay appears [after](http://uploadfile.pl/pokaz/1316257---9lp3.html)

I don't know why is happening, here is the code snippet:

```js
let box = document.getElementById('slider-img');
let sliders = ['url("http://lorempixel.com/800/400/")', 'url("http://lorempixel.com/801/400/")', 'url("http://lorempixel.com/802/400/")', 'url("http://lorempixel.com/803/400/")', 'url("http://lorempixel.com/804/400/")'];
let i = 0;
let navs = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-nav-button");
let left = document.querySelector(".slider-descript-left");
let leftText = ["Project One", "Project Two", "Project Three", "Project Four", "Project Five"]
let right = document.querySelector(".slider-descript-right");
let rightSource = ["link do 1", "link do 2", "link do 3", "link do 4", "link do 5"]
let rightView = ["link do 1", "link do 2", "link do 3", "link do 4", "link do 5"]
let links = right.querySelectorAll("a");

function show() {
  if (i > 0) {
    navs[i - 1].classList.toggle("inner-slider-nav-button");

  } else if (navs[sliders.length - 1].classList.contains("inner-slider-nav-button")) {
    navs[sliders.length - 1].classList.toggle("inner-slider-nav-button");

  }

  box.style.backgroundImage = sliders[i];
  left.querySelector("h2").textContent = leftText[i];
  links[0].href = rightView[i];
  links[1].href = rightSource[i];
  navs[i].classList.toggle("inner-slider-nav-button");

  if (i < sliders.length - 1) {

    i++;


  } else {
    i = 0;

  }

  setTimeout("show()", 4000);

}
show();
```

```css
/* line 108, ../sass/style.scss */

.slider-sec {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #020202;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* line 117, ../sass/style.scss */

.slider-sec .slider-line {
  width: 1px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #7e27fc;
}


/* line 122, ../sass/style.scss */

.slider-sec .slider-line-text {
  color: #7e27fc;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Roboto", serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
}


/* line 133, ../sass/style.scss */

#slider-img {
  animation: ease-in-out slide 4s infinite;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 820px;
  height: 480px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* line 142, ../sass/style.scss */

.slider-box {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


/* line 149, ../sass/style.scss */

.slider-box .slider-descript-left {
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999999;
  top: 16px;
  right: 60px;
  border-left: 2px #7e27fc solid;
  align-self: flex-start;
}


/* line 158, ../sass/style.scss */

.slider-box .slider-descript-left h6 {
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 55px;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #7e27fc;
}


/* line 167, ../sass/style.scss */

.slider-box .slider-descript-left h2 {
  margin-left: 3px;
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #dbdbdb;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=11, Direction=0, Color=#000000)";
  text-shadow: 0 0 11px #000000;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=11, Direction=135, Color=#000000);
}


/* line 179, ../sass/style.scss */

.slider-box .slider-descript-right {
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  border-left: 2px #7e27fc solid;
  align-self: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 16px;
}


/* line 187, ../sass/style.scss */

.slider-box .slider-descript-right h6 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 32px;
  right: 3px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #7e27fc;
}


/* line 197, ../sass/style.scss */

.slider-box .slider-descript-right a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dbdbdb;
}


/* line 202, ../sass/style.scss */

.slider-box .slider-descript-right .fa {
  margin-left: 3px;
}


/* line 208, ../sass/style.scss */

.slider-nav {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
  right: 30px;
}


/* line 214, ../sass/style.scss */

.slider-nav-button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 35px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background-color: #989898;
}


/* line 222, ../sass/style.scss */

.inner-slider-nav-button {
  background-color: #7e27fc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #7e27fc;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40%,
  95% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<article class="slider-sec">
  <div class="slider-line">
  </div>
  <div class="slider-line-text">
    <p>Look My Projects</p>
  </div>

  <section class="slider-box">
    <figcaption class="slider-descript slider-descript-left">
      <h6>branding&design</h6>
      <h2>Project One</h2>
    </figcaption>
    <figure id="slider-img">

    </figure>
    <figcaption class="slider-descript slider-descript-right">
      <h6><a href="#">View project</a><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </h6>
      <h6><a href="#">View source</a><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </h6>
    </figcaption>

  </section>
  <nav class="slider-nav">
    <li class="slider-nav-button"></li>
    <li class="slider-nav-button"></li>
    <li class="slider-nav-button"></li>
    <li class="slider-nav-button"></li>
    <li class="slider-nav-button"></li>
  </nav>
</article>
```

Anyone can see what might be wrong with my code?

Comment: I can't understand the problem from your description. Can you be more explicit about the steps you take to see the issue?

Comment: "another card". What are you calling a card, in this examples? What should we be clicking on, in order to reproduce the issue? I can't see anything much wrong with what is shown.

Comment: Sorry, I added videos showing the problem, I thought maybe something was wrong with my computer, but this delay was on the other computers

Comment: Animation starts faster than changing the image

Comment: could it be that the image has not finished downloading before the animation completes? Most decent image sliders pre-load the next image to avoid this kind of issue.

Comment: At the beginning the animation look good The problem appear when I minimize browser or change the tab It look like the script working but animation stopping

Comment: I did some googling: Javascript is not guaranteed to run animations when the page is in the background, and the way you've implemented it (using timeouts) is problematic because the timeouts continue running, and setting the animations off, but the animations themselves get queued until the page regains focus. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759809/javascript-animation-queueing-when-page-does-not-have-focus . You need to re-design your code

Comment: Okay, thanks it was so helpful